# Asterisk1.6 no such command originate

Tags: asterisk

I installed Asteisk1.6

I tried to use "originate" and I got the no such command error.
I typed "core show help" then no have "origiante" command in list

How can I solve this? or I missing something at the config.
Please tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the Asterisk console, type "manager show commands". You should see it in there. Also, try using "Originate" instead of "originate". It is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

In this thread, within the comments, a fellow says that Originate wasn't added until 1.6.2.

[How to Dial to Originate a Call from Within the Dialplan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906947/how-to-dial-to-originate-a-call-from-within-the-dialplan)

Comment: You can easily tell when the application was added by checking the CHANGES text file, included with Asterisk.

You'll note that the Originate application appears under the section "Functionality changes from Asterisk 1.6.1 to Asterisk 1.6.2"