# How to Dial to Originate a Call from Within the Dialplan?

Tags: asterisk

Salvete!  How can I dial a number and have Asterisk originate a call from extension sipX to sipY?

Both sipX and sipY appear in extensions.conf of my dialplan.

The trick is that I want to dial 337 on my phone, and then my phone goes out of the picture, then sipX calls sipY.

Say I want to be able to push 337 on the phone, and have a sound played over the speakerphone of another phone, say, as an alarm.

---

Another way to consider it is, how can I do this:

1. Push 337 on my phone
2. complete my call, that is, hang up the original caller
3. run a macro even though there is no call in queue
4. call sipY
5. play a sound on sipY

When running the #2 action (completing the caller's session) and letting the rest of the process complete afterward, can we use something like the [pre-dial handlers in Asterisk 11](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pre-Dial+Handlers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer.
You place `Answer` as the first part, and end with 'hangup'.  That takes care of the "busy signal".

No AGI.  This works.

```
[from-internal]
exten => 3334,1,Goto(AngelusBell,startbell,1)


[AngelusBell]
exten => startbell,1,Answer
exten => startbell,n,System(asterisk -rx "channel originate Local/callviking@AngelusBell/n extension playbell@AngelusBell")
exten => startbell,n,Hangup

exten => callviking,1,Dial(SIP/Y,10,D(5))  ;calls my ATA to my paging box and plays 5 tone
exten => callviking,2,Hangup

exten => playbell,1,Answer
exten => playbell,2,Playback(custom/angelusbellWAV)
exten => playbell,3,Hangup
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with the [Originate](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_Originate) application.  Something like the following:

```
[default]
exten => 337,1,NoOp()
same => n,Originate(SIP/Y,exten,default,originated,1)
same => n,Hangup()

exten => originated,1,NoOp()
same => n,Playback(tt-monkeys)
same => n,Hangup()
```

The difference, of course, is that the Originate blocks the pbx_thread executing extension 337 until SIP/Y answers or otherwise fails.  That being said, the actual call between SIP/Y and the application in extension originated occurs on its own thread, so once the state of SIP/Y is known, 337 will be hung up.  So its fairly close to what you were looking for, and doesn't involve external mechanisms like a call file.

Comment: Well, I can tell sipY to answer, as it is a loudspeaker.  This is a good idea.  I am upgrading from 1.2 to 1.8, so I can't try it yet until the upgrade is complete. Originate won't work in 1.2, will it?

If I want to put that in a macro, is this right?
`[macro-callit]`
`exten => s,1,NoOp()`
`same => n,Originate(SIP/Y,exten,default,originated,1)`
...

Comment: Nope, Originate was added in 1.6.2.

You may want to consider using a GoSub instead of a Macro, as Macros have been deprecated in favor of Gosubs (not that it won't work mind you, there's just known limitations with nested Macros that result in hard to debug errors).  But yes, your Macro syntax looks to be correct.

Comment: I think this is the right answer.  I'm still working on my version-change, so I can't test it right now, but this looks good.  Thanks, Mr. Jordan.

Comment: Okay, I'm ugrading my Asterisk from 1.2 to 1.8 and now I can use `Originate()`.  Is there any way to make 337 hang up before it starts the origination?

Comment: So long a time and I'm here again!  I unwittingly google searched and found my own question.  Okay, I've got Asterisk 11.  I can originate the call just fine, but as we knew, it doesn't hang up the calling extension.  Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you use this: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pre-Dial+Handlers  ?

Answer (score 1):

An idea would be to create a call file and move it to /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/ using agi scripts.

Comment: That would be an idea, and it did occur to me, but isn't what I was looking for.