# Originate from a Label within a Macro

Tags: macros, asterisk

How can I originate a call from a label within a macro?

I know this isn't right, but I'm not sure how to work the call viking line into the origination cmd.

The last two lines of the macro comprise what I want to happen in place of "Local/callviking@...".

```
[macro-Paginator]
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,System(asterisk -rx "channel originate Local/callviking@${MACRO_CONTEXT}/n extension ${ARG1}@soundeffects")
exten => s,n,Hangup()
exten => s,n(callviking),Dial(SIP/100,10,D(${ARG2}))
exten => s,n,Hangup()

[soundeffects]
exten => wakeupbell,1(wakeupbell),Answer()
same => n,Playback(custom/bells/daytimebell)
same => n,Hangup()
```

The macro is called like this:

```
[from-internal-custom]  ;freepbx custom context
exten => 23333,1,Macro(Paginator,angelusbell,1) ;Angelus Bell
```

[Here is an example of a method that works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906947/how-to-dial-to-originate-a-call-from-within-the-dialplan/27510981#27510981), except that I want to convert it into a macro so from so I can use the same routine with different dtmf tones (arg2) and soundfiles (arg1)

```
[AngelusBell]
exten => startbell,1,Answer()
exten => startbell,n, NoOp(Ringing-zee dee bell! ${CHANNEL} dialed: ${MACRO_EXTEN})
exten => startbell,n,System(asterisk -rx "channel originate Local/callviking@AngelusBell/n extension ting@soundeffects")
exten => startbell,n,Hangup()
exten => callviking,1,Dial(SIP/100,10,D(5))
exten => callviking,2,Hangup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will work although it isn't very elegant.  It's not a macro, but at least its all in one place:

```
[from-internal-custom]  ;freepbx custom context
exten => 21005,1,Goto(Paginator,test,1)         ;Test Sound     via destination 2005 (is a custom-device-extension so as to be included as a Destination)


[Paginator]
exten => officebell,1,Answer()
exten => officebell,n,System(asterisk -rx "channel originate Local/callviking@${CONTEXT}/n extension ting@soundeffects")
exten => officebell,n,Hangup()

exten => startofficebell,1,Answer()
exten => startofficebell,n,System(asterisk -rx "channel originate Local/callviking1@${CONTEXT}/n extension ting@soundeffects")
exten => startofficebell,n,Hangup()

exten => angelusbell,1,Answer()
exten => angelusbell,n,System(asterisk -rx "channel originate Local/callviking1@${CONTEXT}/n extension ting@soundeffects")
exten => angelusbell,n,Hangup()

exten => test,1,Answer()
exten => test,n,System(asterisk -rx "channel originate Local/callviking1@${CONTEXT}/n extension ting@soundeffects")
exten => test,n,Hangup()

exten => callviking1,1,Dial(SIP/100,10,D(1))
exten => callviking1,n,Hangup()

exten => callviking5,1,Dial(SIP/100,10,D(5))
exten => callviking5,n,Hangup()

;------------------------------------------------------

[soundeffects]
exten => wakeupbell,1(wakeupbell),Answer()
same => n,Playback(custom/bells/daytimebell)
same => n,Hangup()
```